# How can I append values to an empty array in bash shell script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am a beginner in bash script programming. I wrote a small script in Python to calculate the values of a list from an initial value up to the last value increasing with 0.5. The Python script is:

```
# A script for grid corner calculation. 
#The goal of the script is to  figure out the longitude values which increase with 0.5

# The first and the last longitude values according to CDO sinfo
L1 = -179.85
L2 = 179.979
# The list of the longitude values
n = []             

while (L1 < L2):
    L1 = L1 + 0.5
    n.append(L1)

print "The longitude values are:", n 
print "The number of longitude values:", len(n)
```

I would like to create a same script by bash shell. I tried the following:

```
!#/bin/bash
L1=-180
L2=180
field=()

while [ $L1 -lt $L2 ]
do
  scale=2
  L1=$L1+0.5 | bc
  field+=("$L1")

done

echo ${#field[@]}
```

but it does not work. Could someone inform me what I did wrong?
I would appreciate if someone helped me.

Comment: doesn't work? not good enough. Maybe because floating point comparison isn't working in bash?

Comment: Your `she-bang` line is wrong, should have been `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: The array part is fine; it's the assignment to `L1` that is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't correctly assigning the value to `L1`. Also, `-lt` expects integers, so the comparison will fail after the first iteration.

```
while [ "$(echo "$L1 < $L2" | bc)" = 1 ]; do
do
  L1=$(echo "scale=2; $L1+0.5" | bc)
  field+=("$L1") 
done
```

If you have `seq` available, you can use that instead, e.g.,

```
field=( $(seq -f %.2f -180 0.5 179.5) )
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. Both version works correctly.